# How to install Virtualbox 4.3.20 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I m getting the following problems; when I m trying to install Virtualbox,

```
soomaiya@soomaiya-Satellite:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-4.3 : Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
              Recommends: dkms but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
soomaiya@soomaiya-Satellite:~$
```

Please help it out!

Comment: You might just have to download the packages manually. Try searching for the package names and download a .deb package file from apps.ubuntu.com or packages.debian.org

Comment: You probably have some unclean software source added to your system.

Answer (score 0):

`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages` might be a related problem... you could try opening synaptic package manager and clicking Edit -> Fix broken Packages, that might help.

Or the error could refer to the `Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable` error, you also want to update the package info with `apt-cache update` (or in synaptic "Reload package info").

Comment: Its not working